# How to add Margin to DevExpress WPF Controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress

DevExpress WPF is driving me mad with things that are very simple.

How do I add margin around a control in DevExpress WPF? 
For default WPF control, I can simply add a "Margin" property in control, for example:

```
<Button Margin="5" />
```

Done. In DevExpress WPF, there is no Margin property. Take following code as an example - a ComboBox - how do I add Margin to it?

```
<dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="comboBox" Content="ComboBox" EditWidth="100" EditHeight="35">
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>AAA</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>BBB</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>CCC</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [bar item](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6553) is a **non-visual object** that implements a specific functionality so you can't apply visual properties on it directly.
You can set the editor properties via the [BarEditItem.EditStyle](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfBarsBarEditItem_EditStyletopic) property:

```
<dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="comboBox" Content="ComboBox" EditWidth="100">
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
        <Style TargetType="dxe:ComboBoxEdit">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
        </Style>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>AAA</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>BBB</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>CCC</dxe:ComboBoxEditItem>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.Items>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem>
```